# Can I use an 'or' statement in model relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am making a facebook clone. I have a User model and a Request model that includes (sender, recipient, accepted: boolean).

If the recipient accepts it becomes 'true' aka they are friends. How would I set up the following relationship?

```
has_many :friends, -> { where(accepted: true)}, :foreign_key => :recipient_id or :sender_id
```

because if the request is accepted, it doesnt matter if the user is the sender or recipient.

Comment: A user -> friends model should use a join table and be user-to-user. Requests are only requests.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**: NO! Never ever try to use `or` in such ways(and I mean anywhere in your code)! They are **control flow operators**. More explained in details by [Avdi in his blog](http://devblog.avdi.org/2014/08/26/how-to-use-rubys-english-andor-operators-without-going-nuts/)!

**Long answer**: You can follow this awesome railscasts by Ryan bates on [self-referential association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association).

In order to maintain friend requests. You can probably have a model: `FriendRequest` with columns: `state`(if you want to maintain the request state: ignored, blocked, accepted, later etc), `sender_id` and `receiver_id`.

*app/models/user.rb*:

```
has_many friend_requests, foreign_key: :receiver_id # user will be the receiving requests!
has_many sent_requests, foreign_key: :sender_id # user will be the sender, right?
```

*app/models/friend_request.rb*:

```
belongs_to :receiver, class_name: 'User'
belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'User'
```

So, when a user accepts a request then you add their relationship to `Friendship` model. Which will make more sense.